# With ngx-restangular post() , i receive in my json-server PUT /feedback/4?firstname=aa&lastname=aa

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-services

i work with angular 2 and use Restangular.

with my code i see in my json-server this response
and i would like to know how i can save it in my application

```js
OPTIONS /feedback/4?firstname=aa&lastname=aa
PUT /feedback/4?firstname=aa&lastname=aa
```

an advice 
thanks
Cordially

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking and what do you want to save in your application. The code snippet returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I know it's not very clear.

my class Feedback:

```js
export class Feedback {
    firstname:string;
    lastname:string;
    telnum:number;
    email:string;
    agree:boolean;
    contacttype:string;
    message:string;
};
```

i have this function in service

```js
submitFeedback(): Observable<Feedback>{
  return  this.restangular.all('feedback').post(Feedback); 
}
```

in my component, i want retrieve information and send it to my db.json

```js
this.route.params
     
      .switchMap( (feedback:Params) => this.feedbackservice.submitFeedback() )
      .subscribe( feedback => { this.feedback = feedback; this.feedbackcopy = feedback;   }, 
      errmess => this.errMess = <any>errmess );//u
      console.log('feedback::: ' + this.feedbackcopy );
```

via a form

```js
this.feedback = this.feedbackForm.value;
this.feedbackcopy.save(this.feedback)
      .subscribe( feedback => this.feedbackcopy = feedback );
```

I don't know how save "this.feedback" in my db.json

For instance in my db.json only an feedback.id is writting and not the other parameters

```js
"feedback": [
    {
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
```

for me the restangular.post() method isn't clear

I hope to be a little clearest

Cordially

Answer (score 1):

You should pass to this function your JSON as the parameter with type Feedback and then pass it to post:

```
submitFeedback(feedback: Feedback ): Observable<Feedback>{
  return  this.restangular.all('feedback').post(feedback); 
}
```